# It is possible to implement it's own TCP/UDP-like protocol?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, ip, network-protocols

There is the IP - Internet Protocol. It allows us to address some computer in global network - Internet.

There is also a port - endpoint destination on that addressed computer. Someone can establish such an endpoint through socket - a so-named handful of operating system calls (API) and combination of IP address and port. It can be done using one of two "transport" protocols - either TCP or UDP. TCP provides a guarantee of delivery, UDP doesn't. In both cases someone given with a stream of bytes which he/she can read and write back. Such a stream has no meaning as it's own - someone can and should interpret it as he/she likes.

Socket API is well established and straightforward.

There is major wave nowadays: many global companies tend to implement it's own, "brand new" protocols. In fact, seems like many of them just discard using TCP reliable delivery and implement it's own using UDP (what is the reason to fight TCP reliability, though?).

Is there a way to implement a brand new "transport" protocol which will coexists with TCP and UDP? Will it be accessible through socket APIs? If not, then how?

Are there any practical reasons to do this?

Comment: You can implement custom transport-level protocols using RAW sockets, or custom socket stacks.

Comment: UDP is not a byte stream. It is a datagram protocol. SCTP also exists. Too broad.